# Give Role permissions to add Url Redirects in System folder

Tags: security, role-management

I need to give a content author permissions to add url redirects to the folder `/sitecore/system/Modules/Redirect Module`, but I don't want to make them an administrator. How do I do that?

I've tried adding them to the roles that look relavent and still no joy.

Ideally, I want to give them access only to

`/sitecore/system/Modules/Redirect Module`

but if they get access to other Modules in that folder, that's fine to. I just don't want them to be administrators ..

Answer (score 3):

As the Url Redirect module is a 3rd party Sitecore module, by default it doesn't have any access rights applied to it (I just installed and checked to be sure).

You will need to pick your role, or create a specific role, and then assign security rights to the `Url Rewrite` folders that you want editors to be able to read/edit.

I would create 2 roles, `<domain>/Rewrite Read` and `<domain>/Rewrite Write` - that will give you some flexibility on the security.

Also, make sure that the content editors have `Read` access to parent folders, otherwise they will not be able to open the tree to view the `Url Rewrite` module folder.

Comment: Thanks mate. Im half way there ... When I do that, the System folder (and so /System/Modules/Redirect Module) isn't displayed to this user until the View Hidden Items checkbox is checked in the View Tab. And when they do that they can then see Templates, Layouts etc despite not having Read permissions to those folders. Weird! I don't want them to see stuff they don't have permissions to view ..